# Are $A^T B - I$ and $I - A B^T$ equal in Frobenius norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, normed-spaces, rotations, kinematics

Is $\text{frob}(A^T B - I) = \text{frob}(I - A B^T)$, where $\text{frob}$ is the Frobenius norm?

Can you show why?

I ask because, I am curious what is the intuitive meaning of Eq. 4, on page 3 here:https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.07640.pdf

It seems to be just finding the $S$ matrix s.t. $S^{-1}$ is "closest" to $R$, because the Frobenius norm of the difference between two rotations is a rotation metric known as the deviation from the identity matrix: Eq 21, [https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cga/dynopt/readings/Rmetric.pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ecga/dynopt/readings/Rmetric.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purposes of this question, I'll assume that 1) we're only interested in real-valued matrices, and 2) $A,B$ have the same dimensions (since otherwise $A^TB$ isn't square). As such, the Frobenius norm is defined as $\|A \|_F=\sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(A^T A)}$ where $\text{tr}$ is the trace operator. So two matrices $A,B$ are equal in Frobenius norm if $A^T A,B^T B$ have the same trace.

In particular, note that the cyclic property of trace ($\operatorname{tr}(AB)=\operatorname{tr}(BA)$) means that

$$\operatorname{tr}(A^T A)=\operatorname{tr}(AA^T)=\operatorname{tr}((A^T)^T (A^T)).$$
Hence $A^T$ has the same Frobenius norm as $A$ itself. In addition, we have $(-A)^T(-A)=A^T A$ and thus $-A$ also has the same Frobenius norm as $A$. Applying this to $A^TB-I$, we have

$$\|A^T B-I\|_F=\|-(B^T A-I)^T\|_F=\|I-B^T A^T\|_F$$ as asserted.

Comment: The above uses the trace definition of Frobenius norm. One also sees it (equivalently) defined as the square root of the sum of the singular values for the matrix of interest. In those terms, the point is that a matrix's singular values are unchanged by either transposition or by multiplying by $-1$.

Comment: In the above $\lVert M \rVert_F$, is M supposed to be A?

Comment: If your final equality is true, then Eq. 4 and Eq. 21 in the two different papers are not the same. Can you explain what Eq. 4 means then?

Comment: update: It seems what I have derived is that the objective function in Eq. 4 is measuring the chordal distance between $S$ and $R^T$. Can you confirm?

Comment: @user3180 I note that my last equation had a severe typo. Fixed.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the context to speculate. But if $B$ is an orthogonal matrix (as a rotation is) then one may show that $$\|A-B\|_F = \|B(B^{-1}A-I)\|_F = \|B^{-1} A-I\|_F.$$ (The reason is that, if $R$ is an orthogonal matrix, then the matrix $RA$ satisfies $(RA)^T (RA)=A^T R^T R A=A^T A$. So $RA$ has the same Frobenius norm as $A$.) This may connect the two formalisms.

Comment: Is it true also that $\lVert A - B \rVert_F = \lVert B - A \rVert_F$? Intuitively this is true because distance metrics are symmetric.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118277/discussion-between-semiclassical-and-user3180).

Answer (score 0):

No, they aren't equal. You may use the classical example that $XY=0\not\to YX=0$ to construct a counterexample. Let
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0},B=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}.
$$
Then
\begin{aligned}
\|A^TB-I\|_F&=\left\|A^T-I\right\|_F=\sqrt{3},\\
\|I-AB^T\|_F&=\|I\|_F=\sqrt{2}.
\end{aligned}